# Particle effects libgdx

Tags: libgdx, editor, sprite, particle-system

I have made a particle effect using the particle editor that comes with libgdx. Now, I need to provide the particle effect load method 2 arguments - One is the particle file and one is a base image of the particle.

My question is - where can I find the image for the particle, the second argument?

Answer (score 3):

That should be the image(s) you used in the particle editor to create the particle effect.

You'll want to place them on your project assets folder. For example in assets/particles:

`particleEffect.load(Gdx.files.internal("particles/particleEffect.p"), Gdx.files.internal("particles"))`

Answer (score 3):

The first image is the .p image that you generated by particle editor and the second image is the actual image that we can use for the effect, say, sample image of a water drop. You should copy that image into your Asset folder and you should set the path of the second image in your .p file.

1. Copy an image to the asset folder.
2. Double click on .p file.
3. Search for .png file.
4. Set the path for the image that you saved in the asset, e.g. Drop.png.